# How to get the status of sas.servers using codes

Tags: linux, sas

What I want is to get the status of the servers by using the following code:

```
rsubmit;
X 'sh /sas/config/Lev1/sas.servers status';
endrsubmit;
```

Then to using the details to make a monthly report. But the sas.servers file requires a password for it to display the status of the servers.

Please help me how to do this using an external file that contains the password which will be used to execute the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend putting that part of your script in an external file, stored in a directory that is *only accessible to the relevant user(s)*, and calling it via `%include` - eg as follows:

```
rsubmit;
options nosource2; /* ensure contents aren't written to log */
%inc "/mySecurePath/myprog.sas";
endrsubmit;
```

The problem with putting it in a macro variable is that it may be surfaced unintentionally in a log.

Comment: What usually helps there is to either `%symdel` your macro password immediately after use, or set it to a null value.

Comment: I found out that if I run the program using the user it won't require the password. I am now trying to save the status to a log file using the code below:

Comment: 'rsubmit;
X 'sh /sas/config/Lev1/sas.servers status &>> C:\user\mine\logtest.txt';
endrsubmit;'